# Traefik use successfully generated Let's Encrypt certificate on both ports 443 and 8080?

Tags: ssl, https, lets-encrypt, traefik

I want to use Let's Encrypt generated certificates on both ports 443 and 8080 due to legacy compatibility.

I was not able to find anything in the docs concerning the certificates being used on extra ports.

Is there a way to to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Certificates do not mandate a particular port that must be used, only the domain name / IP address. The Let's Encrypt service ACME protocol does its HTTP validation over port 80, though other methods of verification are possible. Once you have the certificate, you can use it anywhere you'd like (as long as the domain name remains valid).

Just curious about the use of 8080 though. That is typically an HTTP port; certificates are only used over secure protocols. The alternate port for HTTPS is 8443.

Comment: That is good to hear, so how do I assign the certificate on second port with traefik?

Comment: about your curiosity: I did not think about what port 8080 is usually used for. I just wanted an often used port as an example my question.